# How "netifaces.gateways" choose default gateway?

Tags: python, linux, python-netifaces

I have 2 network cards on my linux pc, and with next route settings:

```
$ ip route
default via 10.192.244.254 dev enp0s31f6 proto static metric 100
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.106 metric 200
10.192.244.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 10.192.244.193
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.100.0/23 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.106
192.168.100.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.100.106 metric 200
```

In [Metrics (networking)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking)), it said:

> **Router metrics** are metrics used by a router to make routing decisions. A metric is typically one of many fields in a routing table. Router metrics help the router choose the best route among multiple feasible routes to a destination. **The route will go in the direction of the gateway with the lowest metric.**

So, I think the gateway `10.192.244.254` has high priority. But, with next python code:

**try.py:**

```
import netifaces
gateways = netifaces.gateways()
print(gateways)
```

**execution:**

```
$ python3 try.py
{'default': {2: ('192.168.100.1', 'enp2s0')}, 2: [('10.192.244.254', 'enp0s31f6', True), ('192.168.100.1', 'enp2s0', True)]}
```

You can see it just tell me `192.168.100.1` is the default router, why it not choose `10.192.244.254` or show me 2 default routers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I'm on `debian 10`, while the version of `python3-netifaces` is an old version:

```
ii  python3-netifaces 0.10.4-1+b1  amd64
```

On `debian 11`, which used the new library version as next, it works as expected:

```
ii  python3-netifaces 0.10.9-0.2+b3 amd64
```

**execution:**

```
# python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netifaces
>>> gateways = netifaces.gateways()
>>> print(gateways)
{'default': {2: ('10.192.244.254', 'enp0s31f6')}, 2: [('10.192.244.254', 'enp0s31f6', True), ('192.168.100.1', 'enp2s0', False)]}
>>>
```

From [this](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces/pull/71#issuecomment-747401833), I could confirm my issue is a bug of old version and fixed on 2020/12/17 in new `netifaces` version.